# How prove this $d(\alpha,W)$ is Gram determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

if $W$ is subspace of $V$.and $V$ is $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. and $\alpha\in V$, Define the distance from  $\alpha$  to $W$

> $$d(\alpha,W)=|\alpha-\alpha'|$$

where $\alpha'$ is $\alpha$  orthogonal projection on the  subspace  $W$.

such $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3},\cdots,\alpha_{m}$ is $W$ one of  basis.

show that

> $$d(\alpha,W)=\sqrt{\dfrac{|G(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\cdots,\alpha_{m},\alpha)|}{|G(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\cdots,\alpha_{m})|}}$$
>   where $G(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\cdots,\alpha_{m})$ is **Gram matrix**.

my try: since this Gram determinant define:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

But I can't prove this problem,I hope someone can help me.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have covered the relation of the determinant of a Gram matrix and the (hyper)volume of the $m$-dimensional parallelotope $V_m(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)$ determined by having vectors $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ as its edges, namely
$$
V_m(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)=\sqrt{|G(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)|},
$$ 
then your claim follows easily. It is the $(m+1)$-dimensional generalization of the fact that the area of a parallelogram (in the plane) is its base times the height, where height equals the distance of the endpoint of the vector $\alpha_2$ from the baseline generated by $\alpha_1$. In the high-dimensional analogue the $m$-dimensional parallelotope with edges $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ takes the role of the "base", and the distance of the endpoint of the remaining edge vector $\alpha_{m+1}$ from the base takes the role of "height" $h$. So
from the equation 
$$
V_{m+1}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m,\alpha_{m+1})=V_m(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)\cdot h
=V_m(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)\cdot d(\alpha_{m+1},W)
$$
we get
$$
d(\alpha_{m+1},W)=h=\frac{V_{m+1}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m,\alpha_{m+1})}{V_m(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)}=
\sqrt{\frac{|G(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m,\alpha_{m+1})|}{|G(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)|}}.
$$

Comment: Hello,why $V_{m}(\alpha_{1},\cdots,\alpha_{m})=\sqrt{|G(\alpha_{1},\cdots,\alpha_{m})|}?$

Comment: That should be explained in your textbook. One way of seeing that is to do Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization on $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$. You easily see (induction on $m$) that the orthogonalization does not change the value of the determinant of the Gram matrix, nor the $m$-volume of the parallelotope. This reduces the problem to the case, where the vectors $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ are orthogonal. Then the Gram matrix is diagonal, and the relation to the $m$-volume of an $m$-dimensional **rectangular** parallelotope is immediate.